# Adding position fixed for html fullscreen ie11 issue

Tags: javascript, css

I'm implementing full screen functionality using an api, it's working fine for all browsers but in IE `position:fixed` is adding in computed style due to this vertical page scrolling is not occurring. I tried a lot using CSS also but it's not overriding. Can any one help me out?

```js
var element =  document.documentElement;//document.getElementById("fullScreenBody");
   if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
   } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
   } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
   } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
   }
```

```css
html::-ms-backdrop {
 overflow:scroll;
 position:absolute !important;
}
```

I tried using JavaScript also but it's not overriding position : fixed

```
var mydiv = document.querySelector("html");
 mydiv.style.setProperty("position", "relative", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
html {
     position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Maheswaran but it won't work , position : relative is already available for html.

Comment: are you from india?

Comment: give your mobile number , i will explain you